# Dev c++ running the code fine, But codeblocks and ideone are showing errors

Tags: c++

This is my code for reverse polish notation in c++. Its running fine on Dev c++ But code blocks and ideone are giving me errors as segmentation fault. 
debugger shows some error in Ungetwc().

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stack>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    int T;
    char *ex;
    stack<char> u;
    for(scanf("%d",&T);T;T--)
    {

        scanf("%s",ex);

        while(*ex!='\0')
        {
            switch(*ex)
            {
            case '^':
                u.push('^');
                break;
            case '/':
                while(u.top()=='^')
                {
                    printf("%c",u.top());
                    u.pop();
                    }
                 u.push('/');
                 break;
            case '*':
                while(u.top()=='^' || u.top()=='/')
                {
                    printf("%c",u.top());
                    u.pop();
                    }
                 u.push('*');
                 break;
            case '-':
                while(u.top()=='^' || u.top()=='/' || u.top()=='*')
                {
                    printf("%c",u.top());
                    u.pop();
                    }
                 u.push('-');
                 break;
            case '+':
                while(u.top()=='^' || u.top()=='/' || u.top()=='*' || u.top()=='-')
                {
                    printf("%c",u.top());
                    u.pop();
                    }
                 u.push('+');
                 break;
            case '(':
                u.push('(');
                break;
            case ')':
                while(u.top()!='(')
                {
                    printf("%c",u.top());
                      u.pop();
                }
                u.pop();
                break;
            case '\n':
                break;
            default :
                printf("%c",*ex);

            }
            if(*ex == '\n')
                break;
            ex++;

        }

        while(!u.empty())
            {
                printf("%c",u.top());
                u.pop();
            }
            printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[here](http://ideone.com/tE9prN) is my complete code on ideone!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char *ex; [...] scanf("%s",ex);` will input a string to an undefined location. Therefore your code will have undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you wanted to input a single character:

```
char c;
//...
scanf("%c", &c);
while (c != '\0')
{
  switch (c)
//...
```

Also, rather than specifying the constant character to push on the stack, you could use the same variable in the `switch` statement:

```
case '^':
  u.push(c);
  break;
```

Since this task has been completed many times and many questions about it have been posted on StackOverflow, I recommend you search the web for "StackOverflow C postfix calculator".
If you want to use C++ features:  "StackOverflow C++ postfix calculator".